# is there a way to alias a field reference in json_to_recordset

Tags: postgresql

I am using the json_recordset syntax in my query, that looks like this

```
jsonb_to_recordset(t.field_42) as field_42(message text, messageid numeric,tablerowid numeric, addedon timestamp)
```

I'm trying to see if there is a way that I can alias the fields referenced here?
For example, the "addedon" field in the recordset...is there any way to alias this to a different name like "startaddeon" for example?

I've tried to put "as" in the syntax  like this:

```
jsonb_to_recordset(t.field_42) as field_42(message text, messageid numeric,tablerowid numeric, addedon timestamp as 'startaddedon')
```

but it doesn't like that syntaxt.

Comment: Use a complete list of the columns you want to include in `select` (instead of `*`). Then you can alias each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an illustration.

```sql
with the_table(id, field_42) as 
(
 values
 (1, '[
 {"message":"one", "messageid":1, "tablerowid":101, "addedon":"2022-10-06 22:20"},
 {"message":"two", "messageid":2, "tablerowid":102, "addedon":"2022-10-06 22:21"}
 ]'::jsonb),
 (2, '[
 {"message":"three","messageid":3, "tablerowid":103, "addedon":"2022-10-06 22:22"},
 {"message":"four", "messageid":4, "tablerowid":104, "addedon":"2022-10-06 22:23"}
 ]')
)
select t.id, l.message, l.messageid, l.tablerowid, 
       l.addedon as startaddedon -- here it is
from the_table t
cross join lateral jsonb_to_recordset(t.field_42) 
   as l(message text, messageid numeric,tablerowid numeric, addedon timestamp);
```

| id | message | messageid | tablerowid | startaddedon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | 1 | 101 | 2022-10-06 22:20:00.0 |
| 1 | two | 2 | 102 | 2022-10-06 22:21:00.0 |
| 2 | three | 3 | 103 | 2022-10-06 22:22:00.0 |
| 2 | four | 4 | 104 | 2022-10-06 22:23:00.0 |